# Class com.google.ar.core.Frame not found when gradle is compiled with JAVA1.8/

Tags: java, android, java-8, arcore

Android Studio throws the error of class not found when the following is included in gradle file.

```
 compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
```

The error - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.ar.core.Frame not found

In the .java file viewed in Android Studio `import com.google.ar.core.Frame;` is not recognized. The dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.6.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution, if so how? I opend an issue on the ARCore github repo:

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/688

Comment: No I was not able to find the solution, I changed my code and removed lamba expressions.